# Detect which of forms is really active?

Tags: .net, winforms

In my application the user can open multiple forms.

Some forms are MDI, some not.

How can I detect, in a arbitrary (MDI or not) form if it's a active form or not?

from MSDN ([Form.ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) property explanation):

> You can use this method to obtain a reference to the currently active
>   form to perform actions on the form or its controls. If your
>   application is a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, use
>   the `ActiveMdiChild` property to obtain the currently active MDI child
>   form.

I have 2 possibilities, one for MDI, other for non-MDI, but what if I have both forms open, how I detect which of them is really active?

Answer (score 0):

You can place this logic where you need to:

```
        if (Form.ActiveForm == null) return;

        if (Form.ActiveForm == this.MdiParent)
        {
            if (MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild != null) 
                Debug.WriteLine(MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild.Text);

            return;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(Form.ActiveForm.Text);
```

`Form.ActiveForm` will [return the non-MDI form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) that is currenly active. If the Active form is the MDI parent (main window), this will mean that an MDI form is active and so we look at `MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild`

This sample writes Form text to debug out but you can use the info in any way you wish.

Comment: (Form.ActiveForm == null) when I have an MDI open.

Comment: I ran the sample and it's behaving as expected. Is your MDI form the main app form? You could also modify the code and check MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild

Comment: I forgot to note that this code snippet is meant to be executed from the children of the main app form. If you're running this from the main form then the MDIParent property does not make sense.